# Is there any way that I could delete all the data(images) that i uploaded to my google drive through google colab?

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory, drive

For my machine learning project I downloaded more than 10000 images of dogs from kaggles and uploaded it to google drive through colab, now that i don't need those images how can i delete all of them at once.I had have similar experience in the past where I had to delete all the photo manually,but It took me around 3-4 hours to delete those photos. Please help me.

I can delete the photos manually but it will take hours to delete them.